# Backing up VPS via SSH/SFTP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I'm going to perform some maintenance on my VPS (Ubuntu Server 15.04), and I would like to back up some files before doing so. The problem is that some of these files are under other users' home directories or otherwise locked-down places, so I cannot access them normally via SFTP. I considered using a local SSH server to transfer files to my computer (Windows 8.1 x64), but I'm behind a university network and can't forward a port to my computer as would be required to do that.

What is a secure way to get these files to my computer? It's my server, so I obviously have root access, but I don't want to change permissions on things unless I have to.

Comment: I don't really understand how you can not access files if you have root account? When you log into your VM just do `sudo -i` and then you can copy files to wherever you want. If you don't have access to another remote SSH server just make a tar.gz and place it somewhere reachable.

Comment: @mbiber Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. This question actually somewhat evolved into [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276343&p=13276825#post13276825), so I think I'm going to repost that one. Your answer actually does answer my question though--just doing `tar -cvpzf ~/backup.tar.gz /path/to/directory` (with `sudo` as necessary) would be exactly what I need. If you post that I'm more than happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Is `rsync` an option? Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654751/rsync-through-ssh-tunnel helpful?